# ¿Qué significa la sentencia 'int(&)[2];'?

Tags: c++

En el lenguaje de **C++** puedes escribir y compilar el siguiente código:

```
int main(){

   int(&)[2]; //<--------- ¿? 

   return 0;

}
```

¿Qué significa la sentencia `int(&)[2]`?

Comment: ¿Podría ser algo sobre punteros? Algún tipo de anotación o algo... Curiosa pregunta

Comment: @Youshiro No tengo ni idea, llevo 5 años programando en C++ y es la primera vez que lo veo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esa línea no genera código, ni siquiera desactivando las optimizaciones, como puede comprobarse con el siguiente experimento:

```
$ cat ej1.cpp
int main(){
   int(&)[2]; //<--------- ¿? 
   return 0;
}

$ cat ej2.cpp
int main(){
   // int(&)[2]; //<--------- ¿? 
   return 0;
}

$ g++ ej1.cpp -S -O0
$ g++ ej2.cpp -S -O0
$ diff ej1.s ej2.s
1c1
<   .file   "ej1.cpp"
---
>   .file   "ej2.cpp"
```

Es decir, tanto si la línea está como si no el código ensamblador generado es exactamente el mismo (salvo por el nombre del fichero fuente).

Entiendo que para el compilador la expresión `int(&)[2];` da como resultado algún tipo de constante, y por tanto es equivalente a haber escrito:

```
int main(){
   5;
   return 0;
}
```

el cual también es código válido y genera exactamente el mismo ensamblador, pues la constante `5` no es almacenada ni ejecutada.

Ahora bien, por qué el compilador deja pasar `int(&)[2]` y qué puede significar para él se me escapa. Quizás algo más de contexto pueda ayudar ¿dónde lo has visto?

### Edición

En un comentario el usuario menciona que esta expresión la vio en el contexto de *Function parameter list* en [esta página](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack)

Como parámetro de función sí que tiene sentido, pues en ese caso, algo como `int(&)[2]` significa que el parámetro (en este caso sin nombre) es una referencia a un array de dos enteros. Sin embargo en la parte de declaración de variables no le veo sentido y en mi opinión el que sea admitido ahí podría considerarse un bug del compilador.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, he encontrado esta expresión en esta [página](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) en la sección __Function parameter list__ en uno de los comentarios de cómo se expande el pack de parámetros.

Comment: Ah, pero ahí se usa como parámetro de una función. En ese caso, algo como `int(&)[2]` significa que el parámetro (en este caso sin nombre) es una referencia a un array de dos enteros. Sin embargo en la parte de declaración de variables no le veo sentido y en mi opinión el que sea admitido ahi puede considerarse un bug del compilador.

Comment: Gracias de nuevo, quizás debas incluir en la respuesta lo que acabas de comentar. Aunque tengamos la duda del 'posible bug', puedo dar por respondida la pregunta.